# Breeze Validate Entity and its navigational properties

Tags: validation, breeze, one-to-many

I am able to validate an entity using the code `entity.entityAspect.validateEntity()`. However, this does not validate navigation properties. My entiy has one-to-one and one-to-many relationship with out entities. I want to validate both the entity and its navigational properties. How can i do this with breeze?

EDIT
I have a class

```
public class ClassA{
 public int id{get; set;}
 public List<ClassB> navigationArray{get; set;}
}


public class ClassB{
 public int myClass {get; set;}

 [Foreign("myClass")]
 public ClassA ClassA_E{get; set;}
}
```

I add an object O1 of ClassA to the entity manager; and add an object O2 of classB to the entity manager and set the property, ClassA_E to O1. All works well but when validating O1, O2 does not get validated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntityAspect.validateEntity WILL validate navigation properties ( The code below was tested in breeze 1.4.17).

You can add your own validators to any navigation property: In the examples below assume a schema with "Customer" and "Order" entity types where each Customer has an nonscalar "orders" property and each "Order" has a scalar "customer" property.

In this case, the scalar "customer" navigation property on the Order type might have a validator registered like this:

```
var orderType = em.metadataStore.getEntityType("Order");
var custProp = orderType.getProperty("customer");
// validator that insures that you can only have customers located in 'Oakland' 
var valFn = function (v) {
      // v is a customer object
      if (v == null) return true;
      var city = v.getProperty("city");
      return city === "Oakland";
};
var customerValidator = new Validator("customerValidator", valFn, { messageTemplate: "This customer's must be located in Oakland" });
custProp.validators.push(customerValidator);
```

where the validation error would be created by calling

```
myOrder.entityAspect.validateEntity();
```

And the nonscalar navigation property "orders" on the "Customer" type might have a validator registered like this:

```
var customerType = em.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");
var ordersProp = customerType.getProperty("orders");
// create a validator that insures that all orders on a customer have a freight cost > $100
var valFn = function (v) {
    // v will be a list of orders
    if (v.length == 0) return true; // ok if no orders
    return v.every(function(order) {
        var freight = order.getProperty("freight");
        return freight > 100;
    });
};
var ordersValidator = new Validator("ordersValidator", valFn, { messageTemplate: "All of the orders for this customer must have a freight cost > 100" });
ordersProp.validators.push(ordersValidator);
```

where the validation error would be created by calling

```
myCustomer.entityAspect.validateEntity();
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. Now say I have a validate a collection of object. Is there an straightforward way of doing that? This is a suggestion that does not seem to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26675416/807223

Comment: In the data model, say I added defined a field in the order entity as required. for example, the order date is required. Now add an order to a customer object. The order now belongs to a collection of orders, but the added order has not Order Date. Should breeze be able to identify that the customer entity is invalid? ALso, say there is anoher one to many relationship between order and Items where an order can have multiple item and each item has a required name. If I add an item to and order without and name, should breeze be able to determine that the the customer entity is valid?