# Retrieving Validation Errors from Breeze Entity Collection Properties

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, validation, breeze

I have a Breeze entity that has several collections of other entities. When retrieving the validation errors for the first entity, I want to also retrieve the errors from each entity in its collections.

So that if I have an entity `Foo` with many `Bars` and `Bazs`. Is there a generic way to retrieve the validation errors for the `Bars` and `Bazs` on a `Foo` along the lines of `myFoo.getAllValidatioErrors()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one way you could do it:

```
// get primary entity's validation errors.
var validationErrors = entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors()
    // concat all child entity validation errors...
    .concat(            
        // grab every navigation property array.
        entity.entityType.navigationProperties
            .filter(function (propertyInfo) { return !propertyInfo.isScalar; })
            .map(function (propertyInfo) { return entity[propertyInfo.name]; })
            // flatten the array of entity-arrays into one big array of entities.
            .reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b); })
            // validate the entities.
            .map(function (childEntity) { return childEntity.getValidationErrors(); })
            // flatten the array of ValidationError-arrays into one big array of validation errors.
            .reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b); })
    );
```

Comment: getting an error on line .reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b); }). It says a is not a function